# can't push docker image to nexus repository

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I install nexus on docker container and point a sub-domain i.e dj.google.com and it is running on HTTPS.

when i am connecting using localhost or 127.0.0.1, i am able to login but when i am trying using public ip or the url. i am getting error as below :-

`Error response from daemon: Get http://x.x.x.x:9400/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

my question is how can i fix this issue and also if i have multiple repository then do i need to expose multiple port with creating new container or is there another way to do it ?

also inside daemon.json, do i need to mention multiple registries ?